# Extracting / scraping specific information off a website programatically

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I have a public website link from which I need to extract a certain field programmatically.

> https://echa.europa.eu/fr/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/14500

e.g. The section that says "Registrants /Suppliers of the substance"

Answer (score 1):

the simplest thing you can use is Google Sheet - online tool on steroids based on MS Excel.

and all you need is to paste this into some cell:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://echa.europa.eu/fr/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/14500"; 
            "TABLE"; 1)
```

**demo spreadsheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

---

## **`*`bold`*` fix:**

as you can notice, the formula above imports data as is, with the partial formatting of previously bold parts of the text under **B** column. this can be easily eliminated with this formula which converts imported data straight on text with **`TO_TEXT`** and then **`REGEXREPLACE`** converts all **`"\*"`** to **`""`** no space all wrapped in **`ARRAYFORMULA`** to ensure continuity.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(
 IMPORTHTML("https://echa.europa.eu/fr/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/14500"; 
 "TABLE"; 1)); "\*"; ""))
```

**demo spreadsheet of the fix: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4/edit#gid=1873076661)**

[image]